# Get image from header and footer of .docx file in C#

Tags: c#, header, ms-word, footer

I have a .docx file which has images in the footer and the header. How to get the images, knowing which is in the footer and which is in the header?

I tried using:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range = section.Footers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage].Range;
```

but I can't see any properties that would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the InlineShapes ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshapes(v=office.11).aspx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshapes%28v=office.11%29.aspx) property of the Range object. It's a collection of InlineShape ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshape(v=office.11).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshape%28v=office.11%29.aspx)) objects. An Inline object can be any one of several types of objects, and you could check which one it is by accessing the Type property ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshape.type(v=office.11).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshape.type%28v=office.11%29.aspx))

(It has been a almost 2 years since this was asked and I hope the author has found the solution, I added this in case anyone else might find this helpful).

Answer (score 0):

way 1 :

```
 foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape Headershape in OHeader.Shapes)
                        {
                           InlineShape inlineshape = Headershape.ConvertToInlineShape();
                           Range PictureRange = inlineshape.Range;
                           inlineshape.Delete();
                           PictureRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(m_sLogoPath);
                        }
```

Way : 2

```
 foreach (InlineShape shape in OHeader.Range.InlineShapes) 
                            {
                                if (shape.Type == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture)
                                {
                                    shape.Delete();
                                    oSection.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(m_sLogoPath);
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: `var applicationWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
adoc = applicationWord.Documents.Open(ref ofileName);
foreach (Section oSection in adoc.Sections)
foreach (HeaderFooter OHeader in oSection.Headers)`

Comment: `Range PictureRange= Headershape.Anchor; Headershape.Delete(); PictureRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(m_sLogoPath);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var applicationWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
adoc = applicationWord.Documents.Open(ref ofileName);
foreach (Section oSection in adoc.Sections)
{
    foreach (HeaderFooter OHeader in oSection.Headers)
    {
        foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape Headershape in OHeader.Shapes)
        {
            Headershape.Delete();
            OHeader.Shapes.AddPicture(m_sLogoPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Reference : [Word Automation Basics](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx)